# string "2" не конвертируется в int 2

Tags: java, udp

передаю по датаграмм каналу количество элементов коллекции

```java
byte[] intt = Integer.toString(clients.get(IP).size()).getBytes();
        dat_soc.send(new DatagramPacket(intt, intt.length, adr, port));
```

принимаю стрингом

```java
byte[] data = new byte[10];
            ByteBuffer but_buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
            dat_soc.read(but_buff);
            String tipint = new String(data, 0 ,data.length);
int rez = Integer.parseInt(tipint);
```

пытаюсь перевести стринг в инт, но выдает NumberFormatException

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "22"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at lab34.Client.readSer(Client.java:80)
    at lab34.Client.enter_command(Client.java:43)
    at lab34.Client.main(Client.java:51)
```

Comment: в каком месте сам перевод происходит-то?

Comment: перевожу tipint в инт тут и происходит ошибка

Comment: так вы покажите, как вы это делаете, я пока этого не вижу

Comment: пытаюсь через parseInt перевести но что-то оно не работает так же как и valueOf

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.toString(clients.get(IP).size())` - это не перевод `String` в `Int`.

`toString()` выводит информацию о данных в объекте. Чтобы перевести строку в число, надо "спрасить" строку:

```
Integer.parseInt(clients.get(IP).size())
```

Comment: Первая часть не переводит строку в число, а наоборот переводит *число в строку*. Это передающая часть.

Comment: если так делать, то не смогу сериализовать в массив

Comment: первая часть это серверная часть, вторая клиентская. передаю все через датаграмм пакеты. на клиенте десеализовал инт, в данном случае инт "2" но не могу его перевести в инт

Comment: @AnT ?. Это вы про `toString`?

Comment: Да, про `toString`.

Comment: @AnT так я и не говорил что он переводит число в строку

Comment: @AnT заметил опечатку, спасибо